# CasperJS POST AJAX is not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, casperjs

I'm working on sending data through ajax. The code is working, but the AJAX request is not working. The data sent is not saved.

I have tried using `webSecurityEnabled: false`, but it still doesn't work.

This is how I'm trying to do it:

```
var casper = require("casper").create({
    logLevel:   "error", //debug
    verbose:    true,

    pageSettings: {
        loadImages:  true,          // do not load images
        loadPlugins: false,         // do not load NPAPI plugins (Flash, Silverlight, ...)
        webSecurityEnabled: false // ajax 
    }
});

........................

var save_file="http://aaa.com/js_save.php";

for(var ii=0; ii<title_link.length; ii++)
{
    this.echo(title_link[ii]);

    //var save_data = tlink.serialize();
    var save_data = {"title":"title", "link":title_link[ii]};

    jsonObject_fields = this.evaluate(function(save_file) {
        params = save_data;

        try {
            return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(save_file, 'POST', params, false));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error in fetching json object");
        }
    }, {save_file : save_file});

    try{
        //require("utils").dump(JSON.stringify(jsonObject_fields.name));
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log("Error is: "+e);
    }

} // for
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but code-wise you need to explicitly pass variables into the page context. `casper.evaluate` is sandboxed and the only way to pass data between the casper context and the page context is using the arguments and the return value. Variables defined outside cannot be used inside of `casper.evaluate`.

You need to pass `save_data` explicitly to the page context:

```
var save_data = {"title":"title", "link":title_link[ii]};

jsonObject_fields = this.evaluate(function(save_file, save_data) {
    try {
        return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(save_file, 'POST', save_data, false));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Error in fetching json object");
    }
}, save_file, save_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
casper.then(function () {
    var wsurl = "http://siddimaniaajax.esy.es/ajaxCall.php";
    var params = {name:"siddhartha"};

    var jsonObject_fields = casper.evaluate(function(wsurl, params) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(__utils__.sendAJAX(wsurl, 'POST', params, false));
        } catch (e) {
            console.log("Error in fetching json object");
        }
    }, wsurl, params);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(jsonObject_fields));
});

<?php

if(isset($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['name']))
{

 $arr = array('name' => $_POST['name']);
  echo json_encode($arr);
}

?>
```

Comment: an explanation of what you've done and why it works, with links for further reading if needed makes a good answer

Comment: ok, I will , thank you Toni , actually this is my first answer on stackoverflow, thanks for pointing out .